# Netbeans, empty DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jlist

Why is myList empty?

From the output I can see that myList does not have the correct size, yet messages does.

output:

```
Apr 23, 2012 4:28:42 PM net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessagesJFrame <init>
INFO: messages 11
Apr 23, 2012 4:28:42 PM net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessagesJFrame <init>
INFO: myList 0
```

MessagesJFrame:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class MessagesJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MessagesJFrame.class.getName());
    DefaultListModel<Message> myList = new DefaultListModel<Message>();

    public MessagesJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        EnumNNTP nntp = EnumNNTP.INSTANCE;
        List messages = null;
        try {
            messages = nntp.getMessages(false);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.severe("didn't get messages");
        }
        myList.copyInto(messages.toArray());
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "messages {0}", messages.size());
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "myList {0}", myList.size());
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jList1.setModel(myList);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(13, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(129, 129, 129))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(158, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MessagesJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MessagesJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MessagesJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MessagesJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new MessagesJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JList jList1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: ah, Netbeans GUI builders are somewhat incompatible with an SSCCE :(

Comment: No they aren't.  It is just a matter of you understanding how to get them to obey you, rather than allow 'the tail to wag the dog', as seems the case at the moment.  All it would take is to define the `List` in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you add the model to the JList? For a JList to be able to use and display data that's held by a model, the model must be added to the JList either via the JList's constructor or its `setModel(...)` method. Have you gone through the [JList tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)? If not, that's the first place you should look as it will explain how to use JLists and then some.

**Edit 1**
The DefaultListModel `copyInto(...)` method does the opposite of what you think it does. It copies the data from the model into the array.

Per the API:

> Copies the components of this list into the specified array

Comment: It's not so much the `setModel(...)` as how to correctly populate the DefaultListModel, which was showing as empty.

Comment: ohhhhh, thanks, sorry about that, kinda silly question.  You just have to iterate through a collection and invoke `addItem` for each object to add to DefaultListModel?  There's no "bulk add"?

Comment: @Thufir: none that I know of. There's a "bulk" add available via the JList constcuctor, but I'll bet that it's just a convenience, and that under the scenes there's a loop adding each item, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In the narrowest sense, the following code populates the model:

fixed method:

```
public MessagesJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    EnumNNTP nntp = EnumNNTP.INSTANCE;
    List<Message> messages = null;
    try {
        messages = nntp.getMessages(false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.severe("didn't get messages");
    }
    for (Message m : messages) {
        myList.addElement(m);
    }
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "messages {0}", messages.size());
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "myList {0}", myList.size());
}
```

However, what's wrong with `myList.copyInto(messages.toArray());` ?

The above code outputs messages and myList as the same size.

Comment: `INFO: myList 0` which was showing as empty when using `copyInto` but is nonempty using above code.